# Can't store value URL from API contentful in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking

First, I'm so sorry because my English may be not good. I have upload my zip file onto contentful and I use their API to get URL, but I can't stored by my varible. In their code I can print it out console, but out their code it nil and I don't know why!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    client.fetchAsset(id: "2D8m4HqH1iQE8q4qikakkU")  { (result: Interstellar.Result<Asset>) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let asset):
            print("Connect asset succsessful \(asset.id)")
            urlResource = asset.file?.url  //I try to store URL
            print("In: \(urlResource)")    //I can print it out console and it have a value
        case .error(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }

    print("Out: \(urlResource)") // But here it have nil


}//view did load
```

}

Comment: `fetchAsset` executes asynchronously, and executes the code in the closure `{ (result ... }` at a later time.  Your last `print` actually executes *before* the value gets assigned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - Function doesn't wait for results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746192/swift-function-doesnt-wait-for-results)

Comment: It's a block that executes asynchronously, meanwhile, the rest of the code will be executed. That's why you are getting that value as nil

Comment: I have thought about that. I just approached Swift for about two weeks. How can I slove this issue ?